# Jasper print from Java without Dialog

Tags: java, printing

```
String Report = "C:\\Template\\"+file_name+".jrxml";//my Jasper report file
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(Report,null,con);
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
/* Create an array of PrintServices */
PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
int selectedService = 0;
/* Scan found services to see if anyone suits our needs *
for(int i = 0; i < services.length;i++)
{
    if(services[i].getName().toUpperCase().contains("Your printer's name"))
    {
        /*If the service is named as what we are querying we select it */
             selectedService = i;
    }
}
job.setPrintService(services[selectedService]);
PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
MediaSizeName mediaSizeName = MediaSize.findMedia(4,4,MediaPrintableArea.INCH);
printRequestAttributeSet.add(mediaSizeName);
printRequestAttributeSet.add(new Copies(1));
JRPrintServiceExporter exporter;
exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
/* We set the selected service and pass it as a paramenter */
exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE, services[selectedService]);
exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE_SET, services[selectedService].getAttributes());
exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printRequestAttributeSet);
exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PAGE_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.TRUE);
exporter.exportReport();
```

Using the above code to print jasper from java. If I do the above, the print is working fine and it is opening the AWT Dialog where the default values are set, presumably from the system printer (only one default printer). I want to avoid opening the dialog  by changing to `exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);`

But when I do this, it ignores the page layout,size,margins and it takes some default (probably A4 size). How to rectify this ?